# How do I revert to the original OpenGL drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ppa, opengl

I tried to upgrade the OpenGL drivers using `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. When I upgraded my system with this ppa, my desktop manager stopped working properly, so I need to go back to what I was using before. `ppa-purge` is suggested to do this, but it tries to remove all of the desktop manager packages, for some reason. How else can I install the old GL drivers o was using?

Comment: What do you mean by desktop manager packages?

Comment: @Anwar all of the vital packages for the Cinnamon desktop

Comment: _vital_ is still unclear. name them. are you using mint?

Comment: @Anwar yes. I can't remember what packages exactly, but lots of things that had seemingly nothing to do with OpenGL.